# What's your naming convention for the View IDs?

Tags: android

I believe that many of us were bothered while naming the View IDs. Unlike the package mechanism, the IDs of the resources in a project are using one common namespace. Therefore, we have to figure out some ways to name the fields with the same functionality but in different layout files.

My way is to add the noun or the verb that the layout file's Acitvity class name used in the front of the original ID, separated by a dot. For example,an ID originally named "description" in a Activity displaying a movie's information may become "movie.details.description".

Is there any better ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12870537/android-naming-convention

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First I used the same concept but now I try to use more generic ids. In you case I would simply call the id `description`. So you don't need an id for each element and can reuse them as it doesn't matter which layout you're referencing when you call findViewById(R.id.description) you know you get the description element of this layout.

Of course you have to know if you layout has a description element at all. This might be a disadvantage.

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question. Given there is no official style guide that has been released by Google (or the community, which I may be wrong about it but I just didn't find one on Google), then it could be slightly subjective. You have to use the style that makes you and your team comfortable.

My naming convention is the following:

`activityname_elementtype_explicitdescription_suffix`

For instance a button `Login` defined inside the activity `Home` may become:

`home_btn_login`

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to reference activity in you id since it isn't possible to access other activity views using findViewById(). So it's impossible to catch conflict here.

Comment: In this example, it might not make sense. But what about the keys contained in values/string?

Comment: In values/string it's necessary I agree.

Comment: what if the string is used in many places, like "Yes"? i don't think this makes sense. strings shouldn't be tied to usage in a particular place in the application.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman Agreed. Personally, I have a section in my string.xml file specific to those general language words.

Comment: A reason for including the layout name within a widget ID is, that you see at compile-time when the widget is missing from a particular layout.